# How to customize a contributed module's template

Tags: 7, theming

I have a contributed module with a theme file in the module's directory. I want to change it a bit by creating a template file in my custom theme directory. I thought I could just copy and paste the template file into the directory and it would be overridden. That doesn't work, so what am I missing?

Here is the implementation of hook_theme() that's in the .module file:

```
function wunderground_api_theme() {
  return array(
    'wunderground_api_block' => array(
      'template' => 'wunderground_block',
      'variables' => array(
        'weather_data' => NULL,
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: I'm clearing all caches with drush. Still nothing.

Answer (score 1):

To apply changes in templates, you must first rebuild Drupal's theme registry.

Navigate to `/admin/config/development/performance` and click on "Clear all caches" button.

Answer (score 0):

Clear all caches and visit appearance page to reflect theme changes. Theme related cache will be cleared when you are visiting appearance page.